# Programatically obtaining a list from HTML using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, html, dom, htmlunit

I am trying to programatically (in Java) extract the list of articles (title and URL link) corresponding to the particular dates as shown [here](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/h?s=EURUSD=X&t=2013-01-31T00:11:00-05:00).

The result would be something like this:

```
Thursday, January 31, 2013

 - Dollar Curbs Tumble Despite....
 - http://finance.yahoo.com/news/dollar-curbs-tumble-despite-gdp-051100047.html

Wednesday, January 30,2013

 - [video] Santelli's Midday Bond Report
 - http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/video/cnbc/SIG=110mfa5qs/*http://video.cnbc.com/gallery/?video=3000144631&__source=yahoo%7Cheadline%7Cquote%7Cvideo%7C&par=yahoo
```

So, as shown, for a given date, I'm trying to extract all titles/links using HtmlUnit.

The problem is: my knowledge of HTML/DOM is very limited for this trivial task and would appreciate anyone's help who can assist me with this or point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

EDIT:
When inspecting the page, it seems as though the tags I'm looking for are contained within alternating "h3" and "ul" tags. I just don't know how to get to and traverse those tags..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use getElementsByTagName() so you can grab all the <LI>

[http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/api/com/meterware/httpunit/WebResponse.html#getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/api/com/meterware/httpunit/WebResponse.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

first, find table with id "yfncsumtab" :

```
HtmlTable table = page.getElementById("yfncsumtab");
```

then, within table look for `<h3>` and `<ul>`

```
SimpleDateFormatter dateParser = ...
List<DateAndTitle> result = new LinkedList();
Date lastDate = null;

// for(HtmlElement node : table.getHtmlElementDescendants()) {
for(HtmlElement node : findAllChildren(table)) {
    if( "ul".equals( node.getTagName() ) ) {
        String title = node.asText();
        result.add(new DateAndTitle(lastDate, title);
    }
    if( "h3".equals( node.getTagName() ) ) {
        String dateString = node.asText();
        lastDate = dateParser.parse(dateString);
    }
}
```

and helper func to recursively find all descendant html nodes:

```
private HtmlElement findAllChildren(DomNode parent) {
    List<HtmlElement> result = new LinkedList();
    for(DomNode child : parent.getChildren()) {
        if( child instanceof HtmlElement ) {
            result.add( (HtmlElement) child );
        }
    }

    for(DomNode child : parent.getChildren) {
        result.addAll( findAllChildren( child ) );
    }

    retutn result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried the following code, https://gist.github.com/348dcb62ee8a83c32a9b , and it seems like the code never enters the for loop. Instead, I get the following output: https://gist.github.com/ae7d24fd95d323dc7fe9

Answer (score 1):

Just learn [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp). You'll have a 1 to 4 lines solution by using `getFirstByXPath` or `getByXPath`. It's in the [Getting Started](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) page.